# Understanding the Basic Theorem on Concept Lattices

Tags: lattice-orders, galois-connections

In Ganter and Wille's [Applied Lattice Theory: Formal Concept Analysis](http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/~ganter/psfiles/concept.ps), one can find the following definition:

> **Basic Theorem on Concept Lattices.** Let $K := (G, M, I)$ be a formal context. Then $\mathcal B(K)$ is a complete lattice, called the concept lattice of $(G, M, I)$, for which infimum and supremum can be described as follows:
>   $\land_{t\in T}(A_t,B_t)=\left(\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t,\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}B_t\right)''\right)$, 
>  $\lor_{t\in T}(A_t,B_t)=\left(\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}A_t\right)'', \bigcap_{t\in T}B_t\right)$.

where $A \subseteq G$ and $B \subseteq M$. It is based on [Restructuring Lattice Theory: An Approach Based on Hierarchies of Concepts](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-94-009-7798-3_15).

As far as I understand, the second formula (supremum) refers to the topmost node in a lattice. But what about the first formula (infimum)? Is it the lowermost node? If yes, shouldn't there be *exists* instead of *all* at the beginning? It sounds to me like all formal concepts in a complete lattice must have the form of the lowermost node, which doesn't make any sense to me. How should it be interpreted correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by the "topmost node" in a lattice? The formal concept $(G, G')$? These two formulas just describe the operations in this complete lattice. And according to these formulas the infimum of a set of formal concepts is the formal concept that has the intersection of the extents of these concepts as its own extent. Dually, for the supremum you should take the intersection of the intents of these concepts as the intent.

Comment: I have used the term of a node because I had in mind the graphical representation of a lattice (e.g., [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Concept_lattice.svg/360px-Concept_lattice.svg.png)). Everything you said makes sense to me, and now I understand it better. However, when I look at the quantifiers, it seems that a set of formal concepts can have many infima and only one supremum. Based on my observation, the structure of a lattice is symmetrical, and I do not see the reason why it is described like that.

Comment: The theorem states that the concept lattice is complete, that is, arbitrary set of formal concepts has the infimum and the supremum (and they are described by the formulas above). "... can have many infima" - it is not possible at all. If the infimum exists, then it is unique (due to the antisymmetry of an ordering relation). What do you mean by quantifiers? Have you tried to build the concept lattice for some finite small formal context and relate these formulas to the operations in this lattice?

Comment: Yes, I have built some lattices, and I consider your statements about a lattice as true. I understand the idea. In the theorem, there are quantifiers at the beginning of each formula. The first one is "for all", and the second one is "exists". The quantifier in the first formula is something that does not correlate with my understanding of infimum. Could you please write down the first formula literally in natural language? I am asking because I suspect that the mathematical description of infimum has a bad quantifier, and I am looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no quantifiers in these two formulas. I suppose you mixed them ($\forall$ and $\exists$) up with the lattice meet $\wedge$ and join $\vee$ operations.

The complete lattice is a poset in which all subsets have both a supremum and an infimum. So you have two operations $\bigvee$ and $\bigwedge$ (these are just the notations for $\mbox{sup}$ and $\mbox{inf}$ and in case of complete lattices the big signs are usually used instead of small $\vee$ and $\wedge$).

As you probably know the formal concept $C = (A, B)$ consists of the extent $A$ and the intent $B$. The theorem states just that the set of all concepts considered as a poset with the ordering $C_1 \leqslant C_2$ if and only if $\mbox{ext}(C_1) \subseteq \mbox{ext}(C_2)$ forms a complete lattice and the formulas above just provide you the way to compute the infimum and the supremum in this lattice. For clarity, you may replace $\wedge$ with $\mbox{inf}$ and $\vee$ with $\mbox{sup}$ obtaining:
$$\mbox{inf} \{(A_t, B_t) \mid t \in T\} = \left(\bigcap_{t\in T}A_t,\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}B_t\right)''\right)\\
\mbox{sup} \{(A_t, B_t) \mid t \in T\} = \left(\left(\bigcup_{t\in T}A_t\right)'', \bigcap_{t\in T}B_t\right).$$

Informally, in terms of formal concepts you may consider the following interpretation. Let's say that $C_1$ is more general than $C_2$ if $\mbox{int}(C_1) \subseteq \mbox{int}(C_2)$. That means that $C_1$ has less features and therefore can be used to describe more objects, that's why it is "more general". In this case, $C_2$ is called more special than $C_1$ for the same reasons - it has more features, so it can be used to describe only some specific set of objects.

1. The infimum $\bigwedge K$ of $K = \{(A_t, B_t) \mid t \in T\}$ is the "direct specialization" of concepts.
2. The supremum $\bigvee K$ of $K = \{(A_t, B_t) \mid t \in T\}$ is the "direct generalization" of concepts.

Comment: Indeed, I have mixed these symbols with quantifiers. I was unfamiliar with this notion, and the original description gave me no clue. Now everything looks clear. Thank you for your great answer and sorry I can't bump it up (not enough reputation mana).